# IDL: Accessing struct fields using field names stored in variables?

Tags: struct, idl-programming-language

If I have a struct with a fieldname 'fieldname', is it possible to access the data in that field using only the variable?

ie.

x = 'fieldname'

is it possible to do

data = struct.(x) in some way? I want to use the string in x as the field name.

Comment: Nice to see another IDL programmer on SO!  Maybe someday we can reclaim 'our' tag from the likes of those CORBA programmers....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is possible using the `TAG_NAMES` function:

```
tnames=TAG_NAMES(struct)
tindex=WHERE(STRCMP(tnames,'fieldname') EQ 1)
data=struct.(tindex)
```

The call to `TAG_NAMES` returns an array of strings representing the tags defined in `struct`.
The `WHERE` statement returns the index in `tnames` of a string matching `'fieldname'`.
Finally, the index is passed to the `struct.(tindex)` operation, which extracts a field by
its numeric tag index.

Of course, in a real application you'd want to check whether `tindex` was successfully
matched to something, otherwise IDL will choke on the structure lookup with an index
of -1.